# Why do Chinese "extend" the last word when speaking?

Tags: culture, pronunciation, spoken, accent

I've hear on many occasions that Chinese prolong the last word in a sentence, for example:

> ni hao ma ?

becomes

> ni hao maaaaa ?

(I'm not sure that's clear enough but can't think of a better way to describe)

What is the purpose of this? Does it have any cultural meaning? What does it convey?

**Edit:** Perhaps I misunderstood, maybe it's 你好吗啊？ with the 啊 being longer than usual?

Comment: You mean like `Ni hao ma~~~?`

Comment: I tried to say it in different ways, but `ni hao maaaa` does not really ring a bell. On the contrary, `ma` can be very short and shift the sentence into `ni hao me ?`. FYI, am Northerner, it could be a different story from Southerner. :P

Comment: I only notice this with people from Guangdong, something to do with the way they speak in Cantonese maybe? Thai people speak in a very similar way. But I don't think it's universal around China.

Comment: I've updated the question with potential clarification.

Comment: How long specifically? Is the dragging sounds loudly? Is there any other example?

Comment: Nobody say 你好吗啊? When people shout to mountain who want to spread his voice very long distance away will extend last word. It's often seen in movies and commercials.

Comment: Are you sure these are Mandarin speakers? I've noticed elongated sentence-final syllables in Cantonese speakers.  Apparently elongating the final syllable and higher intonation overall is characteristic of questions in Cantonese. [link](http://www.isca-speech.org/archive/sp2006/papers/sp06_033.pdf)

Comment: @user103: I'm am not sure, but they might have been! Unfortunately, I don't have any Chinese friends IRL to check with them..

Comment: If this speaking is usually mixed with a drop in tone on the word before. Like ni/ \hao\ ////ma, it's just a cutesy speak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This kind of case is usually occurs on these occasions:

1. When you are standing at top of the mountain, you feel very exciting, and shout out with prolonging the each word(like `niiiiiii haooooooo maaaaaaa`) or just the last word(like `ni hao maaaaaaa`). Mum, so exciting! :p
2. It usually occurs in young people, especially the female. Some cute girls will often prolong the word in front of her boyfriend. `你好吗~~~(ni hao maaaa)`, `想我吗~~~(xiang wo maaaaaaa)`, etc. This is often described as `嗲(dia3)` in Chinese. When chatting via Internet, `~`/`'`/`.` characters will often used as the word prolonged.
3. Sometimes, wife will do like this in front of her husband. Just like the case No.2. :)

And for your last question: you did not misunderstand. :)

Comment: I did not misunderstand as in "it is 啊" or "it isn't 啊"? :)

Comment: @drHannibalLecter there's no `啊` after `你好吗`. :)

Comment: @drHannibalLecter you're welcome! :D

Answer (score 2):

If this speaking is usually mixed with a drop in tone on the word before, it's just a cutesy speak.

Note that the extended word gets elevated tone, but drops to normal tone right before the end.

```
           /maaaaaa\
ni\       /         \aa
   \_hao_/
```

Girls in japanese anime do that all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It's very uncommon...

What I can think of is... usually when people talk to a baby or when a girl whine to her boyfriend...

Maybe sometimes when a native speaker talk to a foreigner.(I think it's because the person is  afraid the foreigner won't follow what he/she says)

Comment: My friend was often in a Chinese restaurant in Budapest, he says the Chinese there spoke like that all the time amongst themselves. I have also seen/heard it in movies?

Comment: Hey man, how are yoooooooouuuuuuuuuuu? I do that all the time...

Comment: @drHannibalLecter Ah, but were they Mandarin or Cantonese speakers tho?

Comment: @Cocowalla: Good question..I'm not sure really! According to my friend, these weren't even questions, they just talk like that quite often..

Answer (score 1):

I think this is only personal accent. I have never found that pronunciation among people I know. Theoretically, we don't extend any pronunciation, but I think you can do that when you want to emphasize that character.

Answer (score 0):

I think the words didn't get extended.

it's a tone as a question sentence.

Comment: Tone as a question? Can you please elaborate?